# Dificuldade no envio de Imagem para o Banco de Dados

Tags: php, upload

Estou com dificuldade de enviar uma imagem para o meu banco de dados.

Apenas está indo o nome do arquivo mas o File não está sendo Upado para o BD.

Segue o script de Upload:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'editar'):
    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $nome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome'));
    $sobrenome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sobrenome'));
    $email = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
    $usuario = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario'));
    $senha = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha'));
    $descricao = htmlentities($_POST['descricao'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $val->set($nome, 'Nome')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($sobrenome, 'Sobrenome')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($email, 'Email')->isEmail();
    $val->set($usuario, 'Usuario')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($senha, 'Senha')->obrigatorio();
    $val->set($descricao, 'Descricao')->obrigatorio();

    if(!$val->validar()){
        $erro = $val->getErro();
        echo '<div class="erros">Erro: '.$erro[0].'</div>';
    }elseif($foto['error'] == '4'){
        echo '<div class="erros">Informe uma imagem padrão!</div>';
    }else{
    $nomeImg = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).$foto['name'];
    $painel->upload($foto['tmp_name'], $foto['name'], $nomeImg, '350', '../usuarios/');
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $_SESSION['downs_email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['downs_senha'] = $senha;

        $atualizar_dados = BD::conn()->prepare("UPDATE `usuarios` SET `nome` = ?, `sobrenome` = ?, `email` = ?, `usuario` = ?, `senha` = ?, `descricao` = ?, `foto` = ?
        WHERE `id` = ?");
        $dados_atualizar = array($nome, $sobrenome, $email, $usuario, $senha, $descricao, $nomeImg, $usuarioLogado->id);
        if($atualizar_dados->execute($dados_atualizar)){
            echo '<script>alert("Dados atualizados com sucesso!");location.href="?pagina=configs"</script>';
        }else{
            echo '<script>alert("Ocorreu algum erro ao editar");location.href="?pagina=configs"</script>';
        }
    }
endif;
```

Segue a Função de Upload:

```
function upload($tmp, $name, $nome, $larguraP, $pasta){

    $ext = end(explode('.', $name));
    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'JPEG'){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'png'){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'gif'){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);
    }
    list($larg, $alt) = getimagesize($tmp);
    $x = $larg;
    $y = $alt;
    $largura = ($x>$larguraP) ? $larguraP : $x;
    $altura = ($largura*$y)/$x;

    if($altura>$larguraP){
            $altura = $larguraP;
            $largura = ($altura*$x)/$y;
    }
    $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);
    imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0,0,0,0, $largura, $altura, $x, $y);

    imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.$nome);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nova);
    return (file_exists($pasta.$nome)) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Com que tipo de dados você esta guardando o anexo na Base de Dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você salvar a imagem em si, em um campo do tipo BLOB no banco de dados você deve utilizar:

```
$conteudoImagem = file_get_contents($foto['tmp_name']);
```

e substituir no array $nomeImagem por $conteudoImagem:

```
$dados_atualizar = array($nome, $sobrenome, $email, $usuario, $senha, $descricao, $conteudoImagem, $usuarioLogado->id);
```

Comment: @GustavoJanctsch......muito obrigado meu colega programador me salvou meu brother. Sou amador e ainda estou aprendendo vlw por compartilhar seu conhecimento

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você deve salvar a imagem no servidor e no banco de dados você salva apenas o caminho de onde a imagem foi salva.

**Por exemplo:**

Você salva o arquivo `avatar.jpg` em `/var/www/html/upload/images`

No banco de dados você deve salvar `'/var/www/html/upload/images/avatar.jpg'` ou apenas o nome da imagem para recupera-la em um outro momento concatenando o caminho com o nome.

Comment: meu amigo eu já tentei de tudo um pouco até cheguei a conclusão que o melhor caminho seria utilizar o Insert ao invés do Upload. Mas sempre tem acontecido a mesma coisa meu amigo. Apenas está passando para o BD a string do File. Eu uso EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9.....se poder me ajudar cara...eu agradeço